# What regulation says that a manufacturer must support a fleet above a specific size?

Tags: regulations

Beechcraft bought back Starship to reduce the size of the flying fleet so they could stop supporting them. What regulation defines the fleet size a manufacturer has to support?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you tell us where you got the information about the regulations? [This fairly detailed article](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/aviation-international-news/2008-07-28/bulk-starship-fleet-headed-incinerator) makes it sound like a purely business decision, it doesn't mention regulations at all (unless I missed it).